# Nested Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, nested-loops

I'm trying to run nested loops in Access VBA. Each hour (0 to 23) of the day loops through the recordset and prints each instance the hour falls between BeginHour and EndHour fields. It appears the inner loop is only running once although i = 24 at the end of the procedure.

Sample Record set:

```
BeginHour   EndHour     Desired Result
    9        10              9
   10        11             10
   10        11             10
   10        12             10
                            10
```

Code:

```
Sub hourCount()
Dim myDatabase As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer

Set myDatabase = CurrentDb
Set rst = myDatabase.OpenRecordset("DailyData_BTJob")

For i = 0 To 23
Do While Not rst.EOF
  If i >= rst!BeginHour And i <= rst!EndHour Then
    Debug.Print i
  End If
rst.MoveNext
Loop
i = i + 1
Next

Set myDatabase = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't understand  why you are incrementing i in the loop. The For loop handles that for you.

Comment: Good Eye, I actually posted the working copy I removed the incrementer.

Comment: Figured it out. Missing rst.MoveFirst for the inner loop.